# Using escape=false with output text isn't allowing scroll

Tags: visualforce, html, scrolling, outputtext, escape

I have a list of html strings I want to render with html formatting, so I put it in a string list and implemented on the vfp with outputtext and escape = false. If the list is long enough without the escape = false a scroll bar appears, but when I use escape = false no scroll bar appears when it is off the page. Any ideas?

```
<apex:outputPanel >
                
    <apex:repeat value="{!bodies}" var="account" id="theTable">
             <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!account}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
                
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example value of the account html as well as any css associated with the id theTable? Just using the code above I'm unable to recreate this issue.

Comment: @TylerCampbell that gave me an epiphany... it was that my visualforce email template had the scroll-y hidden duh... thanks